# How to split a long string based on delimiter in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a column having few records with long string which I want to split based on delimeter `\n-`

for example in below dataframe I want to split the values in a second column based on delimeter from second record onwards by keeping first record as it is

```
Sr_no    Col1
1        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text
2        \n- Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text,\n- Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text ,\n- Lorem 
         Ipsum is simply dummied text

3        \n- Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text,\n- Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text ,\n- Lorem 
         Ipsum is simply dummied text
.        .
.        .
.        .
```

I wish to get an output like

```
Sr_no    Col1                                    Col2                   Col3                                   
1        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text
2        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text

3        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text
.        .                                       .
.        .                                       .
.        .                                       .
```

I tried using `str_split()` and `str_split_fixed()` in R but I was not able to do. Thanks for any help

Comment: What do you want the output to look like? I.e. what do you want to do with the part after the first split in each of the records with the delimiter?

Comment: @DanAdams - I want to split the string across multiple column based on delimeter. Please see the above edit in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it as long as you know the maximum number of parts you expect.

```
dat <- data.frame(
  Sr_no = 1:3,
  Col1 = c("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text",
           "\n- Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text,\n- Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text ,\n- Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text",
           "\n- Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text,\n- Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text ,\n- Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text")
) 


dat %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Col1 = str_remove(Col1, "^\n-\\s*")) %>% # assuming you dont want an empty first column for entries starting with the delim
  tidyr::separate(Col1, into=c("Col1","Col2","Col3"), sep="\\s*,*\\n-\\s*")
```

If you don't know how many colums you could split the column itself like this:

```
dat$Col1 %>%
  stringr::str_remove("^\\n-\\s*") %>%
  stringr::str_split("\\s*,*\\n-\\s*", simplify=T) %>%
  data.frame()
```

EDIT: With a ',\\n- ' as the delimiter and ' \\n- ' as the initial prefix:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  Sr_no = 1:3,
  Col1 = c(" \\n- Agent confirmed the number to work with",
           " \\n- Agent confirmed the number to work with,\\n- $4 processing fee charged,\\n- Payment completed successfully,\\n- Agent successfully updated the card info for Autopay",
           " \\n- Agent confirmed the number to work with,\\n- Agent confirmed the zip-code")
) 

dat %>%
  mutate(Col1 = str_remove(Col1, "^\\s\\\\n-\\s")) %>%
  tidyr::separate(Col1, into=c("Col1","Col2","Col3"), sep=",\\\\n-\\s")

dat$Col1 %>%
  stringr::str_remove("^\\s\\\\n-\\s") %>%
  stringr::str_split(",\\\\n-\\s", simplify=T) %>%
  data.frame()
```

Comment: Thanks @Devin, maximum number of part is expected to be around 113 and so I tried the second solution provided by you but unfortunately it doesn't work for me

Comment: What does not work? It splits the example column as expected.

Comment: I am trying to view this dataframe (as my dataframe is very wide and long to see the output in console) so I stored the output in one dataframe `dat$Col1 %>%
  stringr::str_remove("^\n-\\s*") %>%
  stringr::str_split("\\w*,*\n-\\w*", simplify=T) %>%
  data.frame() -> df`  and trying to view  `View(df)` but it doesn't show any change. For the given example it is working well.

Comment: I can't guess what is happening on your end. Please post a minimal reproducible example where the solution does not work.

Comment: here is the structure of my dataframe : ```> dput(head(resolution_steps,4))
structure(list(`summary resolution` = c(" #NotALearnedResponse", 
" \\n- Agent confirmed the number to work with", " \\n- Agent confirmed the number to work with,\\n- $4 processing fee charged,\\n- Payment completed successfully,\\n- Agent successfully updated the card info for Autopay", 
" \\n- Agent confirmed the number to work with,\\n- Agent confirmed the zip-code"
), Freq = c(3L, 12L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")```

Comment: This is what I am trying to do ```resolution_steps$`summary resolution` %>%
  stringr::str_remove("^\n-\\s*") %>%
  stringr::str_split("\\w*,*\n-\\w*", simplify=T) %>%
  data.frame() -> df``` and using `View(df)` to see the changes but there is no change

Comment: You just need to find the right regex for your actual data (which is different that the example you posted in your original question). I edited my answer to add one that would work for the data you posted in the comment. Also, there was a mistake in my original answer that I fixed - it was working for the wrong reason!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how many columns you expect in the output, `splitstackshape::cSplit()` works well.

Since you have a delimeter starting the strings in your example, you will end up with an empty column unless you remove those first, so I did that with `stringr::str_replace()` which just `replace`s the first `pattern`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(splitstackshape) 

d <- tibble(Sr_no = 1:3,
            Col1 = c("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text", rep("\n- Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text,\n- Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text ,\n- Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text", 2)))

d %>% 
  mutate(Col1 = str_replace(Col1, "\\n- ", "")) %>% 
  cSplit("Col1", "\n-")
#>    Sr_no                              Col1_1
#> 1:     1  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text
#> 2:     2 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text,
#> 3:     3 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text,
#>                                  Col1_2                             Col1_3
#> 1:                                 <NA>                               <NA>
#> 2: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text , Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text
#> 3: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text , Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @Dan Adams, it works well for this example but I notice something that if you do `View(d)` or `View(as.data.frame(d))` you will see the dataframe is not same, because of which it is not spliting my wide and long dataframe properly. Any suggestion why this is happening?

Comment: When you run `View()` in Rstudio - the IDE is rendering the data object for you with some formatting. It is seeing the newline escape sequence (`\n`) and creating a line break and removing it from the displayed data. If you just print `d` to the console, you'll see the *actual* data. The way it appears in the Rstudio viewer is misleading in this case.

Comment: Yes thanks @Dan Adams, In my case- when I am running `View()` for my dataframe it is actually showing` \n-` in the strings so when I am using your solution the columns are splits with `\n` at the end of the string also the first column holds `\n` values separately.

Answer (score 0):

In base R use

```
cbind(dat['Sr_no'], read.csv(text=gsub('\n- ', '', dat$Col1), header = FALSE))

  Sr_no                                 V1                                  V2                                 V3
1     1 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text                                                                       
2     2 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text
3     3 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text
```